# Django Form Wizard, how to reset/clear wizard?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I have created a Django Form Wizard which works fine. However, after finishing the wizard and starting it again, it loads the data generated during its previous use. Instead I would like it to clear the previous wizard state and start over once it was finished successful. I have tried modifying the done method of the wizard, but it doesn't do the trick:

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    self.instance_dict = {}
    self.storage.reset()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/foo/')
```

What do I have to change to make the wizard work the way I need it? My wizard extends the `NamedUrlSessionWizardView` class.

Comment: Try to add: *self.storage.current_step = self.steps.first*. Is there something new with this line of code?

Comment: Try to send a GET request to a page where your wizard works with parameter: ?reset=true. Does it reset the wizard?

Comment: adding ?reset=true or ?foo=randomvalue didn't help either.

Comment: As I understand '?reset=true' must reset your wizard (it's a bit in the source code).

Comment: Hmm, I think it didn't when I tried it, but I can't check it anymore as I moved to a completely different approach. Thanks for your help anyways!
Maybe someone else who experiences the same issue and lands here can check and confirm it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this is true, but I think the following worked:

I was saving instances of forms in my wizard like this:

```
self.instance_dict['foo'] = foo
```

but for some reason

```
self.instance_dict = {}
```

didn't clear that data. Instead I moved to saving the objects in extra data:

```
self.storage.extra_data = {'foo' : foo}
```

Which I then retrieve inside the `def get_form_instance(self, step)` method of the wizard, for example like this:

```
def get_form_instance(self, step):
    ...
    if self.steps.current == 'foo' and self.storage.extra_data.has_key('foo'):
        return Bar.objects.filter(foo=self.storage.extra_data['foo'])
    ...
```

That data apparently got cleared successfully with the above mentioned done method. However, in the end I dropped the whole form-wizard thing due to more complications and just went with a one-step form.

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy to reset the storage of a Form Wizard. I usually do that after the data processing is finished:

```
def done(self, form_list, form_dict, **kwargs):
    #do stuff with your form data
    self.instance_dict = None
    self.storage.reset()
    return redirect(reverse_lazy('somewhere'))
```

Or reset the Wizard after the redirect from another view

```
del request.session['wizard_name']
```